# Expected Unqualified Error ID Xcode C++ GLFW GLAD

Tags: c++, xcode

I am new to Xcode OpenGl Glad and C++ and am just trying to make it compile, any help would be awesome. I just really don't understand what to do with this error, what am I missing here?

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

{
    int main()
    {
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
      
        return 0;
    }
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
    void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

Comment: What's the deal with that lonely `{` sitting between the include directives and `main`? Remove it and see if you still have the same error.

Comment: You'll still have some errors because there's oodles of code outside of functions.

Comment: Common coding guidelines for C++ has the function declarations at the top of the source file, after all the `#include` but before the first function *definition*.

Comment: Looks like you're not familiar enough with the fundamentals of C++ yet. Start smaller with simple programs to get a handle on the language and come back to complicated stuff like graphics programming later.

Answer (score 0):

80% of your code is nowhere(nor in main neither in other function)